# Matplotlib's fill_between doesnt work with plot_date, any alternatives?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I want to create a plot just like this:
[image: This has integer x values]

The code:

```
P.fill_between(DF.start.index, DF.lwr, DF.upr, facecolor='blue',   alpha=.2)
P.plot(DF.start.index, DF.Rt, '.')
```

but with dates in the x axis, like this (without bands):
[image: with plot_date]

the code:

```
P.plot_date(DF.start, DF.Rt, '.')
```

the problem is that fill_between fails when x values are date_time objects.

Does anyone know of a workaround? DF is a pandas DataFrame.

Comment: In this recipe it is show as working: http://matplotlib.org/users/recipes.html#fill-between-and-alpha but I get the following error: condition = ~(np.isfinite(a))
TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Comment: output of DF.info():
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 967 entries, 0 to 966
Data columns (total 9 columns):
SE       967 non-null int64
start    967 non-null object
end      967 non-null object
cases    967 non-null int64
Rt       961 non-null float64
Rt2      967 non-null float64
p1       967 non-null float64
lwr      967 non-null float64
upr      967 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(5), int64(2), object(2)
memory usage: 75.5+ KB
None

Comment: Convert the numpy datetime64[ns] type to an array of python datetime.datetime objects by using `to_pydatetime()`. Solution taken from [here](https://github.com/facebook/prophet/issues/33).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It would help if you show how `df` is defined. What does `df.info()` report? This will show us the dtypes of the columns.

There are many ways that dates can be represented: as strings, ints, floats, datetime.datetime, NumPy datetime64s, Pandas Timestamps, or Pandas DatetimeIndex. The correct way to plot it depends on what you have.

Here is an example showing your code works if `df.index` is a DatetimeIndex:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats

index = pd.date_range(start='2000-1-1', end='2015-1-1', freq='M')
N = len(index)
poisson = (stats.poisson.rvs(1000, size=(N,3))/100.0)
poisson.sort(axis=1)
df = pd.DataFrame(poisson, columns=['lwr', 'Rt', 'upr'], index=index)

plt.fill_between(df.index, df.lwr, df.upr, facecolor='blue', alpha=.2)
plt.plot(df.index, df.Rt, '.')
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

If the index has string representations of dates, then (with Matplotlib version 1.4.2) you would get a TypeError:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats

index = pd.date_range(start='2000-1-1', end='2015-1-1', freq='M')
N = len(index)
poisson = (stats.poisson.rvs(1000, size=(N,3))/100.0)
poisson.sort(axis=1)
df = pd.DataFrame(poisson, columns=['lwr', 'Rt', 'upr'])

index = [item.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for item in index]
plt.fill_between(index, df.lwr, df.upr, facecolor='blue', alpha=.2)
plt.plot(index, df.Rt, '.')
plt.show()
```

yields

```
  File "/home/unutbu/.virtualenvs/dev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/ma/core.py", line 2237, in masked_invalid
    condition = ~(np.isfinite(a))
TypeError: Not implemented for this type
```

In this case, the fix is to convert the strings to Timestamps:

```
index = pd.to_datetime(index)
```

Comment: What if the date column consists of Pandas datetime64 objects? Sholud I convert it to something else? Is there a way of using fill_between() on these objects?

Comment: There should be no problem; `plt.plot` and `plt.fill_between` accept arrays of dtype `datetime64[ns]` just fine.

Comment: @unutbu When I use datetime64 and `plt.fill_between()` I get: `TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''`. So the reason of this error should be somewhere else?

Comment: @chilliq: Could you prepare a small example which exhibits the problem, and post it in a new question? Googling `TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types` shows this error can possibly arise due to the version of matplotlib, or when using a NumPy array of dtype 'object'. And there are likely other reasons as well. So it's hard to know what is causing your problem without having a reproducible example.

Comment: @unutbu [Posted question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29329725/pandas-and-matplotlib-fill-between-vs-datetime64)

Comment: I would up with that ufunc error at one point because my dates were in the wrong form. I converted them to datetimes and the ufunc error went away and everything ran smooth.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the error reported by chilliq:

```
TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs 
  could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting 
  rule ''safe''
```

This can be produced if the DataFrame columns have "object" dtype when using fill_between. Changing the example column types and then trying to plot, as follows, results in the error above:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats

index = pd.date_range(start='2000-1-1', end='2015-1-1', freq='M')
N = len(index)
poisson = (stats.poisson.rvs(1000, size=(N,3))/100.0)
poisson.sort(axis=1)
df = pd.DataFrame(poisson, columns=['lwr', 'Rt', 'upr'], index=index)
dfo = df.astype(object)

plt.fill_between(df0.index, df0.lwr, df0.upr, facecolor='blue', alpha=.2)
plt.show()
```

From dfo.info() we see that the column types are "object":

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 180 entries, 2000-01-31 to 2014-12-31
Freq: M
Data columns (total 3 columns):
lwr    180 non-null object
Rt     180 non-null object
upr    180 non-null object
dtypes: object(3)
memory usage: 5.6+ KB
```

Ensuring that the DataFrame has numerical columns will solve the problem. To do this we can use pandas.to_numeric to convert, as follows:

```
dfn = dfo.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')

plt.fill_between(dfn.index, dfn.lwr, dfn.upr, facecolor='blue', alpha=.2)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

I got similar error while using fill_between:

```
ufunc 'bitwise_and' not supported
```

However, in my case the cause of error was rather stupid. I was passing color parameter but without explicit argument name which caused it to be #4 parameter called `where`. So simply making sure keyword parameters has key solved the issue:

```
ax.fill_between(xdata, highs, lows, color=color, alpha=0.2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think none of the answers addresses the original question, they all change it a little bit.

If you want to plot timdeltas you can use this workaround

```
ax = df.Rt.plot()
x = ax.get_lines()[0].get_xdata().astype(float)
ax.fill_between(x, df.lwr, df.upr, color="b", alpha=0.2)
plt.show()
```

This work sin your case. In general, the only caveat is that you always need to plot the index using pandas and then get the coordinates from the artist. I am sure that by looking at pandas code, one can actually find how they plot the timedeltas. Then one can apply that to the code, and the first plot is not needed anymore.

Comment: Only answer that worked for me with timedeltas as index.