# Pandas and Matplotlib - fill_between() vs datetime64

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

There is a Pandas DataFrame:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 300 entries, 5220 to 5519
Data columns (total 3 columns):
Date             300 non-null datetime64[ns]
A                300 non-null float64
B                300 non-null float64
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(2)
memory usage: 30.5 KB
```

I want to plot A and B series vs Date.

```
plt.plot_date(data['Date'], data['A'], '-')
plt.plot_date(data['Date'], data['B'], '-')
```

Then I want apply fill_between() on area between A and B series:

```
plt.fill_between(data['Date'], data['A'], data['B'],
                where=data['A'] >= data['B'],
                facecolor='green', alpha=0.2, interpolate=True)
```

Which outputs:

```
TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs
could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting 
rule ''safe''
```

Does matplotlib accept pandas datetime64 object in `fill_between()` function? Should I convert it to different date type?

Comment: This workaround should work for both `plt` and axes `plt.fill_between( data['Date'].dt.to_pydatetime(), data['A'],...`. It converts numpy datetime64[ns] to python's datetime that fill_between understands.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

[Pandas registers a converter](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/tseries/converter.py#L27) in `matplotlib.units.registry` which converts a number of datetime types (such as pandas DatetimeIndex, and numpy arrays of dtype `datetime64`) to matplotlib datenums, but it does not handle Pandas `Series` with dtype `datetime64`.

```
In [67]: import pandas.tseries.converter as converter

In [68]: c = converter.DatetimeConverter()

In [69]: type(c.convert(df['Date'].values, None, None))
Out[69]: numpy.ndarray              # converted (good)

In [70]: type(c.convert(df['Date'], None, None))
Out[70]: pandas.core.series.Series  # left unchanged
```

`fill_between` checks for and uses a converter to handle the data if it exists.

So as a workaround, you could convert the dates to a NumPy array of `datetime64`'s:

```
d = data['Date'].values
plt.fill_between(d, data['A'], data['B'],
                where=data['A'] >= data['B'],
                facecolor='green', alpha=0.2, interpolate=True)
```

---

For example,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

N = 300
dates = pd.date_range('2000-1-1', periods=N, freq='D')
x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, N)
data = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.sin(x), 'B': np.cos(x),
               'Date': dates})
plt.plot_date(data['Date'], data['A'], '-')
plt.plot_date(data['Date'], data['B'], '-')

d = data['Date'].values
plt.fill_between(d, data['A'], data['B'],
                where=data['A'] >= data['B'],
                facecolor='green', alpha=0.2, interpolate=True)
plt.xticks(rotation=25)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The workaround works perfectly - thank you very much. This behaviour is quite strange, what could be the reason here?

Comment: @chilliq: My first suggestion was to use a DatetimeIndex. It turns out that is not necessary. It is quicker to simply use `data['Date'].values` to extract the underlying NumPy array from the Pandas Series.

Comment: This is very helpful, I was not aware of that. I belive that this little trick is going to solve many of my problems with plotting DataFrames with Matplotlib.

Comment: Bizarre, but this works with %matplotlib qt  but not inline

Comment: @unutbu I've got a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52020099/how-to-fill-the-area-between-two-lines) I tried to incorporate your answer but I get `KeyError: 'Date'` any suggestions?

Answer (score 9):

As WillZ pointed out, Pandas 0.21 broke unutbu's workaround. Converting datetimes to dates, however, can have significantly negative impacts on data analysis. This solution currently works and keeps datetime:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

N = 300
dates = pd.date_range('2000-1-1', periods=N, freq='ms')
x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, N)
data = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.sin(x), 'B': np.cos(x),
           'Date': dates})
d = data['Date'].dt.to_pydatetime()
plt.plot_date(d, data['A'], '-')
plt.plot_date(d, data['B'], '-')


plt.fill_between(d, data['A'], data['B'],
            where=data['A'] >= data['B'],
            facecolor='green', alpha=0.2, interpolate=True)
plt.xticks(rotation=25)
plt.show()
```

[image: fill_between with datetime64 constraint]

EDIT: As per jedi's comment, I set out to determine the fastest approach of the three options below:

- method1 = original answer
- method2 = jedi's comment + original answer
- method3 = jedi's comment

method2 was slightly faster, but much more consistent, and thus I have edited the above answer to reflect the best approach.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import time


N = 300
dates = pd.date_range('2000-1-1', periods=N, freq='ms')
x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, N)
data = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.sin(x), 'B': np.cos(x),
           'Date': dates})
time_data = pd.DataFrame(columns=['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10'])
method1 = []
method2 = []
method3 = []
for i in range(0, 10):
    start = time.clock()
    for i in range(0, 500):
        d = [pd.Timestamp(x).to_pydatetime() for x in data['Date']]
        #d = data['Date'].dt.to_pydatetime()
        plt.plot_date(d, data['A'], '-')
        plt.plot_date(d, data['B'], '-')


        plt.fill_between(d, data['A'], data['B'],
            where=data['A'] >= data['B'],
            facecolor='green', alpha=0.2, interpolate=True)
        plt.xticks(rotation=25)
        plt.gcf().clear()
    method1.append(time.clock() - start)

for i  in range(0, 10):
    start = time.clock()
    for i in range(0, 500):
        #d = [pd.Timestamp(x).to_pydatetime() for x in data['Date']]
        d = data['Date'].dt.to_pydatetime()
        plt.plot_date(d, data['A'], '-')
        plt.plot_date(d, data['B'], '-')


        plt.fill_between(d, data['A'], data['B'],
            where=data['A'] >= data['B'],
            facecolor='green', alpha=0.2, interpolate=True)
        plt.xticks(rotation=25)
        plt.gcf().clear()
    method2.append(time.clock() - start)

for i in range(0, 10):
    start = time.clock()
    for i in range(0, 500):
        #d = [pd.Timestamp(x).to_pydatetime() for x in data['Date']]
        #d = data['Date'].dt.to_pydatetime()
        plt.plot_date(data['Date'].dt.to_pydatetime(), data['A'], '-')
        plt.plot_date(data['Date'].dt.to_pydatetime(), data['B'], '-')


        plt.fill_between(data['Date'].dt.to_pydatetime(), data['A'], data['B'],
            where=data['A'] >= data['B'],
            facecolor='green', alpha=0.2, interpolate=True)
        plt.xticks(rotation=25)
        plt.gcf().clear()
    method3.append(time.clock() - start)

time_data.loc['method1'] = method1
time_data.loc['method2'] = method2
time_data.loc['method3'] = method3
print(time_data)
plt.errorbar(time_data.index, time_data.mean(axis=1), yerr=time_data.std(axis=1))
```

[image: time test of 3 methods on converting time data for plotting a DataFrame]

Comment: This is a faster & simpler workaround `plt.fill_between( data['Date'].dt.to_pydatetime(), ...`. That also works with `axes.fill_between`.

Comment: @jedi Thank you for the recommendation. I have edited the answer in response to your comment.

Answer (score 4):

I encountered this issue after upgrading to Pandas 0.21. My code ran fine previously with `fill_between()` but broke after the upgrade.

It turns out that this fix mentioned in @unutbu 's answer, which is what I had before anyway, only works if the `DatetimeIndex` contains `date` objects rather than `datetime` objects that has time info.

Looking at the example above, what I did to fix it was to add the following line before calling `fill_between()`:

```
d['Date'] = [z.date() for z in d['Date']]
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. 
I have a DataFrame that looks something like this:

```
date        upper     lower 
2018-10-10  0.999614  0.146746
2018-10-26  0.999783  0.333178
2019-01-02  0.961252  0.176736
2019-01-08  0.977487  0.371374
2019-01-09  0.923230  0.286423
2019-01-10  0.880961  0.294823
2019-01-11  0.846933  0.303679
2019-01-14  0.846933  0.303679
2019-01-15  0.800336  0.269864
2019-01-16  0.706114  0.238787
```

with dtypes:

```
date     datetime64[ns]
upper           float64
lower           float64
```

The following results in the error from the initial post

```
plt.fill_between(dplot.date, dplot.lower, dplot.upper, alpha=.2)
```

Interestingly,

```
plt.fill_between(dplot.date.values, dplot.lower, dplot.upper, alpha=.2)
```

works perfectly fine.