# How to plot min max line plot in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

Hi I have a data frame in the following format.

For simplicity i am showing the data categorized as years, but it has the quarterly data. 
I want to do a line plot with min max as shadow and mean as a line plot. I tried different ways to do it but i am not able to get it in the output i need shown below.

As an alternative a box plot with mean, min and max will also work.

**Data format**
[image]

**Output Needed**

[image]

Comment: Have you considered [`seaborn.tsplot`](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.tsplot.html)? Seems to do what you're after, though you might need to reshape the data a bit.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

IIUC, groupby YEAR and aggregate your Value column by max, min and mean, then plot mean and use fill_between to do the coloring inside max and min.

```
data = df.groupby('YEAR')['VALUE'].agg({'Low Value':'min','High Value':'max','Mean':'mean'})
data.reset_index(inplace=True)

ax  = data.plot(x='YEAR', y='Mean', c='white')
plt.fill_between(x='YEAR',y1='Low Value',y2='High Value', data=data)
```

[image]

Comment: I found that in the `groupby` statement `as_index = False` is required for this to work.

Comment: And, in case you're using a date on the x-axis, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29329823/10797326) about how to deal with differences in date format between pandas and matplotlib.