# How can plot errorbar style using scatter plot for min & max values instead of mean & std over time within dataframe in python?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, plotly-express

Let's say I have the following datafarme:

```
+-------------------+--------+--------+--------+
|timestamp          |average |min     |max     |
+-------------------+--------+--------+--------+
|2021-08-11 04:05:06|2.0     |1.8     |2.2     |
|2021-08-11 04:15:06|2.3     |2.0     |2.7     |
|2021-08-11 09:15:26|2.5     |2.3     |2.8     |
|2021-08-11 11:04:06|2.3     |2.1     |2.6     |
|2021-08-11 14:55:16|2.6     |2.2     |2.9     |
|2021-08-13 04:12:11|2.1     |1.7     |2.3     |
+-------------------+--------+--------+--------+
```

I want to plot `average` values in the form of a *scatter plot* and also plot `min` and `max` columns using a dashed *line plot* and then fill between areas `average` & `max` as well as `average` & `min` **separately** as it is shown in fig 1 in the table.

I found some close examples:

- [How to create a min-max plot by month with fill_between](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43384034/10452700)
- [How to plot min max line plot in python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43384034/10452700)

---

I aim to develop this to reach something like [`plt.errorbar()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/plot_types/stats/errorbar_plot.html) (which deals with mean and std) [example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57453989/10452700), [example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57120164/10452700) **but** I just want to illustrate `min` and `max` values instead of ~~mean & std~~ over time  as follows:

| [image: img] | [image: img] |
| --- | --- |
| Fig. 1: without errorbar style. | Fig. 2: with errorbar style. |

sadly I could not find the output example for *fig 2* since normally they used to translate mean and std with data points but for *fig 1* this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57120164/10452700) but it for [r](/questions/tagged/r) language is what part of what I want but the area color should be filled with different color (light red and blue) separately.

Any help and guidance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have not specified the library of visualizations to use, I have `plotly.graph_objects` created the graph for your purposes. The graph will consist of a scatter plot line type with error bars, and a scatter plot line type with maximum, average, and minimum lines. The reason why I am drawing the line of averages is to paint the maximum and minimum. The only difference from the output in your question is the color of the lines in the error bars. plotly automatically processes time series data on the x-axis.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=df['timestamp'],
    y=df['average'],
    marker=dict(size=10, color='black'),
    line_color='blue',
    name='average',
    error_y=dict(
        type='data',
        array=df['max']-df['average'],
        arrayminus=df['average']-df['min'],
        visible=True)
    ))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=df['timestamp'],
    y=df['max'],
    mode='lines',
    line=dict(color='rgba(255,0,0,1.0)', dash='dash'),
    fill='tonexty',
    fillcolor='rgba(255,0,0,0.5)',
    name='max'
))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=df['timestamp'],
    y=df['average'],
    mode='lines',
    line_color='rgba(0,0,0,0)',
    fill='tonexty',
    fillcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)',
    showlegend=False
))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=df['timestamp'],
    y=df['min'],
    mode='lines',
    line=dict(color='rgba(0,0,255,1.0)', dash='dash'),
    fill='tonexty',
    fillcolor='rgba(0,0,255,0.5)',
    name='min'
))

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your proposed solution nevertheless gives me [this](https://i.imgur.com/0s8jNOd.png) output which hast slightly diffrent with expected output for *Fig. 2: with errorbar style.* (markers for average are missing in plot and legend for average) and errorbars are totally blue while it should be partially red and blue. Additionaly can you extend your solution for *Fig. 1: without errorbar style.* as well?

Comment: Markers for the average are specified in the first graph. Is this setting missing? `marker=dict(size=10, color='black')` And as I mentioned in my answer, plolty unfortunately does not have the ability to paint error bars. The only way to deal with Figure 1 is to draw horizontal lines at the necessary points.

Comment: Yes, in first graph `mode='lines+markers'` is missing.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you should give copy&paste ready data, so you can get more help from others ;)

If i understand you right you can build you plot step by ste and this should lead to the wanted output:

```
from io import StringIO

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# You should give data in a better form to make it easier to help you, so somebody can copy/paste data
data = StringIO("""
timestamp|average|min|max
2021-08-11 04:05:06|2.0|1.8|2.2
2021-08-11 04:15:06|2.3|2.0|2.7
2021-08-11 09:15:26|2.5|2.3|2.8
2021-08-11 11:04:06|2.3|2.1|2.6
2021-08-11 14:55:16|2.6|2.2|2.9
2021-08-13 04:12:11|2.1|1.7|2.3
""")

df = pd.read_table(data, delimiter="|")

# draw area between max/average and min/average
plt.fill_between(x='timestamp', y1='average', y2='max', data=df, color="lightcoral")
plt.fill_between(x='timestamp', y1='average', y2='min', data=df, color="lightblue")

# draw dashed lines of min/max
plt.plot(df["timestamp"], df["max"], "r--")
plt.plot(df["timestamp"], df["min"], "b--")

# draw vertical lines from min/max to average
plt.vlines(df["timestamp"], df["max"], df["average"], color="red")
plt.vlines(df["timestamp"], df["min"], df["average"], color="blue")

# draw dots of average
plt.plot(df["timestamp"], df["average"], "k.")

plt.show()
```

for me, it gives the following result:

[image]

I didn't prettefied the stuff around, but i think that isn't a problem for you to show nice axes and so on.

Comment: hey, thanks for your input. It's a quite straightforward solution that can adapt to *fig 1* and *fig 2* scenarios.