# MatPlotLib, datetimes, and TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types…

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, numpy, matplotlib

Here is a tiny piece of code that produces a filled in region between two lines of a graph:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(0.0, 2, 0.01)
y1 = np.sin(2 * np.pi * x)
y2 = 1.2 * np.sin(4 * np.pi * x)

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1, 1, sharex=True)

# Test support for masked arrays.
ax1.fill_between(x, 0, y1)
ax1.set_ylabel('between y1 and 0')
y2 = np.ma.masked_greater(y2, 1.0)
ax1.plot(x, y1, x, y2, color='black')
ax1.fill_between(
    x, y1, y2, where=y2 >= y1,
    facecolor='green',
    interpolate=True)
ax1.fill_between(x, y1, y2, where=y2 <= y1, facecolor='red', interpolate=True)
ax1.set_title('Now regions with y2>1 are masked')

# Show the plot.
plt.show()
```

It looks like so:

[image: Plot generated by the code]

Now, changing the start so that `x` is now a collections of date times objects like so:

```
import datetime

x1 = np.arange(0.0, 2, 0.01)
now = np.datetime64(datetime.datetime.now())
x = np.array([now - np.timedelta64(datetime.timedelta(seconds=i)) for i in range(200)])
y1 = np.sin(2 * np.pi * x1)
y2 = 1.2 * np.sin(4 * np.pi * x1)
```

yields:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                File "fill_between_demo.py", line 21, in <module>                             
    ax1.fill_between(x, 0, y1)                                                  
  File "/home/usr/.virtualenvs/raiju/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1898, in inner                                                  
    return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)                                            
  File "/home/usr/.virtualenvs/raiju/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 4778, in fill_between                                         
    x = ma.masked_invalid(self.convert_xunits(x))                               
  File "/home/usr/.virtualenvs/raiju/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/ma/core.py", line 2388, in masked_invalid                                               
    condition = ~(np.isfinite(a))                                               
TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

*Why is that happening and how to fix it?*

Note that plotting the data (aka not using `fill*`) works just fine.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is, that the numpy ufunc `isfinite` is not defined for the `numpy.datetime64` dtype. There is an effort to change this, though. This [issue on numpy's github](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5610) is being worked on in this [pull-request](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/7856), but as long as this is not finished up and merged, you will not be able to use `isfinite` on that dtype. This is a problem as `matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between` is using this function implicitly, when calling `numpy.ma.masked_invalid` to mask all invalid entries of your input array.

There is a work-around though. As pointed out in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29329823/6614295) to a similar question concerning `fill_between` plotting of a pandas `Series` of `datetime64` type, pandas registers a custom converter for (among others) numpy arrays of `datetime64` dtype with matplotlib. To make use of that, you simply have to import pandas:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
# import pandas for its converter that is then used in pyplot!
import pandas

x1 = np.arange(0.0, 2, 0.01)
now = np.datetime64(datetime.datetime.now())
x = np.array([now - np.timedelta64(datetime.timedelta(seconds=i))
              for i in range(200)])
y1 = np.sin(2 * np.pi * x1)
y2 = 1.2 * np.sin(4 * np.pi * x1)

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1, 1, sharex=True)

# Test support for masked arrays.
ax1.fill_between(x, 0, y1)
ax1.set_ylabel('between y1 and 0')
y2 = np.ma.masked_greater(y2, 1.0)
ax1.plot(x, y1, x, y2, color='black')
ax1.fill_between(
    x, y1, y2, where=y2 >= y1,
    facecolor='green',
    interpolate=True)
ax1.fill_between(x, y1, y2, where=y2 <= y1, facecolor='red', interpolate=True)
ax1.set_title('Now regions with y2>1 are masked')

# Show the plot.
plt.show()
```

will work and give you your desired output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with ax.setxlims, because I forgot to cast some datetime to np.datetime.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> import numpy
>>> a = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> numpy.isfinite(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
>>> a = numpy.datetime64(a)
>>> numpy.isfinite(a)
True
```

It looks like it is no longer required to import pandas