# matplotlib fill_between raises errors of "ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types..."?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to fill the gap between two lines in a plot using matplotlib, but it always shows an error message like below. I have checked there is a similar question [posted in the forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45432735/matplotlib-datetimes-and-typeerror-ufunc-isfinite-not-supported-for-the-inp/45433424), but their solutions do not solve this problem.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl, os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#read and convert data from an excel file to two dimensional numpy.array
df = pd.read_excel("Water.xlsx").values

#x axis is year, from 1900 to 2017
year = np.arange(1900,2018,1)

#read data from df and convert them to one-dimensional numpy.array 
W_low = df[:,[29]].ravel()
W_high = df[:,[30]].ravel()

#plot the two lines and fill in the gap 
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1, 1, sharex=True)
#no errors are raised until this line
ax1.fill_between (year, W_low, W_high)
```

Error message

```
  File "C:\Users\Christina\.spyder-py3\temp.py", line 24, in <module>
    ax1.fill_between (year, W_low, W_high)

  File "C:\Users\Christina\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1599, in inner
    return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\Christina\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 5233, in fill_between
    y1 = ma.masked_invalid(self.convert_yunits(y1))

  File "C:\Users\Christina\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\ma\core.py", line 2377, in masked_invalid
    condition = ~(np.isfinite(a))

TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Comment: I had the same issue. Turned out my x was a list and the bounds (W_low and W_high in your case) were ndarrays. Converted everything to list and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem myself. It seems that the dataset I used previously was not clean enough. I copy-pasted the whole dataset to a new excel sheet, and run the same script then it works perfectly.

Hope my solution will help others who have encountered the same problem.