# datetime64 values, ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I would like to plot graphs with gradient. As an example, here the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon

def main():
    # This works
    # x = np.array([0,1,2])

    # This not
    x = np.array('2015-12-23 12:51:00',dtype='datetime64[ns]') 
    x = np.insert(x, 0, ('2015-12-24 12:51:00'))
    x = np.insert(x, 0, ('2015-12-25 12:51:00'))
    
    y = np.array([1,2,99])
    gradient_fill(x, y)
    plt.show()


def gradient_fill(x, y, fill_color=None, ax=None, **kwargs):
    """
    Plot a line with a linear alpha gradient filled beneath it.

    Parameters
    ----------
    x, y : array-like
        The data values of the line.
    fill_color : a matplotlib color specifier (string, tuple) or None
        The color for the fill. If None, the color of the line will be used.
    ax : a matplotlib Axes instance
        The axes to plot on. If None, the current pyplot axes will be used.
    Additional arguments are passed on to matplotlib's ``plot`` function.

    Returns
    -------
    line : a Line2D instance
        The line plotted.
    im : an AxesImage instance
        The transparent gradient clipped to just the area beneath the curve.
    """
    if ax is None:
        ax = plt.gca()

    line, = ax.plot(x, y, **kwargs)
    if fill_color is None:
        fill_color = line.get_color()

    zorder = line.get_zorder()
    alpha = line.get_alpha()
    alpha = 1.0 if alpha is None else alpha

    z = np.empty((100, 1, 4), dtype=float)
    rgb = mcolors.colorConverter.to_rgb(fill_color)
    z[:,:,:3] = rgb
    z[:,:,-1] = np.linspace(0, alpha, 100)[:,None]

    xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax = x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), y.max()
    im = ax.imshow(z, aspect='auto', extent=[xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax],
                origin='lower', zorder=zorder)

    xy = np.column_stack([x, y])
    xy = np.vstack([[xmin, ymin], xy, [xmax, ymin], [xmin, ymin]])
    clip_path = Polygon(xy, facecolor='none', edgecolor='none', closed=True)
    ax.add_patch(clip_path)
    im.set_clip_path(clip_path)

    ax.autoscale(True)
    return line, im

main()
```

If the x values have the datatype float it works. If I use the datetime values as x the following error is shown:

```
    if not np.any(np.isfinite(xys)):
TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

I've installed numpy-1.23.1. As referred here: [MatPlotLib, datetimes, and TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45432735/matplotlib-datetimes-and-typeerror-ufunc-isfinite-not-supported-for-the-inp)
There was a issue and change requests years ago https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/7856
According to my understanding this should be fixed since NumPy 1.17

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a matplotlib bug; see https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/22105

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed in matplotlib. Imshow's *extents* values may now be unitful (will support datetime values). It will be out in the next release.