# Unable to add lines to `axes` used by pandas `plot` method

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I find the `pandas` `DataFrame.plot` method very useful and I especially like the way it formats the x ticks when the x variable is a date. However, there are times when I want to add more complicated marks on top of a plot that was generated using `DataFrame.plot`. For example, plotting a time series using `ax = my_timeseries_df.plot("date", "value)` and then calling the `fill_between` method on the `ax` object to add confidence intervals. However, when I call a plotting method on an `ax` object after using it with `pandas` I can't get any marks to show up.

Here is an example:

[image]

And here is the raw code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

test = pd.DataFrame({
    "a": pd.date_range(start="2020-04-21", periods=5, freq="D"),
    "b": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    "c": [2, 4, 6, 8, 10],
})
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
test.plot("a", "b", ax=ax)
ax.plot(test.a, test.c, color="red", linewidth=20)
```

Strangely the y-limit changes after calling `ax.plot(...)` to accommodate the new points, but the new line does not appear.

I have tried adding `%matplotlib inline` to the cell but that doesn't help. I could always just bypass `DataFrame.plot` and use `matplotlib` for everything, but dealing with time-based x-ticks directly in `matplotlib` is annoying enough that I would love to let `pandas` do it for me.

Comment: Please copy and paste the example code into your answer, so we can copy and paste it into our editors.

Comment: This question may be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29329725/pandas-and-matplotlib-fill-between-vs-datetime64

Comment: @Joooeey good call, I added the raw code.

Comment: You could try `ax.set_xlim(auto=True)` to figure out if the line is plotted on a different part of the x-axis. This can happen when using different modules (Pandas and Matplotlib) that handle the dates differently.

Comment: No dice with `ax.set_xlim(auto=True)` unfortunately.

Comment: There is an issue with differing x-values as you can see when calling `ax.lines[0].get_xydata()` and `ax.lines[1].get_xydata()`. Good luck with figuring this out! I need some sleep now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `x_compat=True`, see docs [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.0/visualization.html#suppressing-tick-resolution-adjustment):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

test = pd.DataFrame({
    "a": pd.date_range(start="2020-04-21", periods=5, freq="D"),
    "b": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    "c": [2, 4, 6, 8, 10],
})
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
test.plot("a", "b", ax=ax, x_compat=True)
ax.plot(test.a, test.c, color="red", linewidth=20)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: You are correct. It's a bummer that you lose the tick formatting though. The formatting is pretty much the only reason I use the `pandas` `plot` instead of just doing it all in `matplotlib`.

Answer (score 1):

Also, for reference, `matplotlib` has a couple of classes that make it much easier to get closer to the tick formatting that `pandas` has baked in; `AutoDateLocator` and `ConciseDateFormatter`. Although they still don't get you complete parity. You can get the [docs here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/ticks_and_spines/date_concise_formatter.html).

```py
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

test = pd.DataFrame({
    "a": pd.date_range(start="2020-04-21", periods=5, freq="D"),
    "b": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    "c": [2, 4, 6, 8, 10],
})
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
locator = mdates.AutoDateLocator(minticks=3, maxticks=10)
formatter = mdates.ConciseDateFormatter(locator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)

ax.plot(test.a, test.b)
ax.plot(test.a, test.c, color="red", linewidth=2)
```

[image]