# Matplotlib fill_between

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to use `fill_between` with a pandas Series values but it's not working. The `'DAY'` field is string date format like `'%Y-%m-%d'`.

`df_tmp` like:

```
MEDIA_B2W  MEDIA_CONC  UPPER_BOUND  LOWER_BOUND     DAY
2017.48     2512.55       2811.0       1924.0       2017-01-01
1999.38     2512.55       2811.0       1924.0       2017-01-02
1930.89     2512.55       2811.0       1924.0       2017-01-03

df_tmp[['UPPER_BOUND','LOWER_BOUND','MEDIA_CONC','MEDIA_B2W','DAY']].plot(
                 x='DAY',ax=ax[0],grid=True,style=['r-','b-','y--','g-o'])

ax[0].fill_between(df_tmp.index,df_tmp['UPPER_BOUND'], df_tmp['LOWER_BOUND'],
                    facecolor='green', alpha=0.2, interpolate=True)
```

I would like to color between the upper and lower bound.
This is the [current plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9sme.png)

Just the lines appear in the plot.

Comment: Can you show your plot and explain how it's different from what you are looking to get? Preferably also include a few rows of `df_tmp`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matplotlib's fill\_between doesnt work with plot\_date, any alternatives?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28091290/matplotlibs-fill-between-doesnt-work-with-plot-date-any-alternatives)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This workaround uses `df` indices for x ticks, and then swaps for the time series.

```
df = df[['UPPER_BOUND','LOWER_BOUND','MEDIA_CONC','MEDIA_B2W','DAY']]

ax = df.plot(x=df.index, grid=True, style=['r-','b-','y--','g-o'])
ax.fill_between(df.index, df.LOWER_BOUND, df.UPPER_BOUND,
                facecolor='green', alpha=0.2, interpolate=True)

# replace index values with dates
ax.set_xticks(df.index)
ax.set_xticklabels(df.DAY)

# cosmetic adjustments
pad = 700
ax.set_ylim([df.LOWER_BOUND.min()-pad, df.UPPER_BOUND.max()+pad])
```

[image: fill-between time series]

Alternately, you can set `DAY` as `df.index`:

```
df.DAY = pd.to_datetime(df.DAY)
df = df.set_index('DAY')

ax = df.plot(grid=True, style=['r-','b-','y--','g-o'])
ax.fill_between(df.index, df.LOWER_BOUND, df.UPPER_BOUND,
                facecolor='green', alpha=0.2, interpolate=True)

# cosmetic adjustments
pad = 700
_=ax.set_ylim([df.LOWER_BOUND.min()-pad, df.UPPER_BOUND.max()+pad])
```

[image: fill between 2]